# Build array with one textbox c# , asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to build a form that allows a user to enter 100 different measurements. Then enter 100 different weights. I want to use the same text boxes. One for the measurements, one for the weights.  Then have them store the value and then reset to accept the next value and so on. Can anyone point me in the right direction to accomplish this? I have searched for over an hour and can't find anything. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When user clicks submit button, add to list or dictionary your value of both textboxes. Do this until wanted number of list.Count is reached. Let me know if I didn't understand your question right.

*In WPF (C#) it would look something like this.*

```
// Dictionary to save values
Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();

// Method that is called on user submit button click
private void HandleSubmit(object sender, EventArgs args) {
    // Add values of both textboxes to dictionary
    dict.Add(textBox1.Text, Int32.Parse(textBox2.Text));

    // Check if all data is entered
    // then activate custom method
    if(dict.Count >= 100) {
        CUSTOMMETHOD(dict);
    }
}
```

-- EDIT --

@briskovich As I understood your comment. You want to save all 100 pressure samples first and then enter 100 weight samples. In that case there is no need to use dictionary, you could use two List<int> for pressure and weight. In that case, code would look something like this:

```
// Variables to save our data
// numberValues - number of values user needs to enter
// pressureList - list of entered pressure data
// weightList - list of entered weight data
int numberValues = 100;
List<int> pressureList = new List<int>();
List<int> weightList = new List<int>();

// Method that is called on user submit button click
// This method uses only one text box to input data,
// first we input pressure data until limit is reached 
// and then weight data
private void HandleSubmit(object sender, EventArgs args) {
    // Check if we are still entering pressure data, that
    // is until we reach numberValues of pressure data values
    // Same thing goes for weight list
    if (pressureList.Count < numberValues) {
        pressureList.Add(Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text));
    }
    else if (weightList.Count < numberValues) {
        weightList.Add(Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text));
    }
    else {
        // When we have #numberValues of values in both 
        // lists we can call custom method to process data
        CUSTOMMETHOD(pressureList, weightList);
    }
}

// Method for processing data
private void CUSTOMMETHOD(List<int> pressures, List<int> weights) {
    // This loop will go through all values collected and
    // will give you access to both pressure and weight on
    // each iteration
    for (int index = 0; index < numberValues; index++) {
        int currentPressure = pressures.ElementAt(index);
        int currentWeight = weights.ElementAt(index);

        // Do processing here
    }
}
```

Comment: This sample is generic enough that it is not WPF specific, unlike you have noted.  This sample works for winforms or even webforms too.

Comment: The values will be added one at a time in each box. So 100 pressure samples then the 100 weight samples. So then I can just pull those values out of the dictionary and manipulate them in other methods?

Comment: @briskovich I added another sample that would fit more to you.